# Is there an atomic way to update_option in Wordpress (to ensure data integrity)?

Tags: php, wordpress, transactions, atomic

I want to update an option which is an array by adding a new value, but there's no atomicity or guarantee of data integrity.

**EXAMPLE**

```
//Get the option value (an array)
$val = get_option( "some-option" );

//Add to the array
$val[] = "something";

/** Here, another session might already have it and is calling "update_option" */

//Save back (this overwrites whatever that other person did)
update_option( "some-option", $val );
```

Is there anything in wordpress that offers atomicity?

Comment: You may get a quicker answer @ the [Official WordPress Exchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to add a second option that acts as a data lock.

You'd perform a check to see if the lock came back false before being allowed to modify the option.

After giving it some more thought however wouldn't a custom table better suit your needs. If you have multiple people updating the same option a table makes more sense.

Anyway, here's how the lock could work:

```
if ( false === get_option( 'some-option-lock' ) )  {
    update_option( 'some-option-lock', true );

    $val = get_option( "some-option" );

    //Add to the array
    $val[] = "something";

    update_option( "some-option", $val );

    update_option( 'some-option-lock', false );
}
```